# Authenticate user by oAuth and add application account under privacy settings, to achieve Single Sign On

Tags: ios, authentication, oauth, sdk, single-sign-on

I am developing an ipad application which uses admin login through oAuth. I am able to get the access token and make service calls.

But I want to add my application account under privacy settings like Facebook, Twitter. So that admin can go to settings and he can add another account or he can modify the existing one. Like "**Account Manager**" in Android.

For instance, I want to add an account under Facebook, Twitter. In the account, the admin can enter username and password.

I will Appreciate your help.